# Existence of continuous real-valued function that is not bounded

Tags: limits, continuity

Suppose that $S$ is a subset of a metric space $X$ that is not closed. Show that there is a continuous real-valued function on $S$ that is not bounded.

Let $f$ be a function on $S$. We need to show that $f$ is continuous real-valued and is not bounded. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Since $S$ is not closed there is a point $x_0$ in the boundary of $S$ that doesn't belong to $S.$ What can you say about the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{d(x,x_o)}?$

Comment: It is a nice answer!